# Making elements rearrange on mobile (responsive layout)

Tags: css, vue.js, responsive-design, quasar

This is potentially a very basic question, but I'm fairly new to flexbox and responsive layouts.

I have a page that on desktop looks like this

[image: desktop]

this is the code I used to get this layout

```
<div style="width: 100%">
        <div class="row justify-center">
            <h2>Link statistics</h2>
        </div>
      <div class="row justify-center items-center q-gutter-sm">
            <div class="col-4 items-center">
                    <q-list bordered separator>
                        <q-item clickable v-ripple>
                            <q-item-section>
                                <q-item-label><strong>Original URL:</strong>&nbsp;<a :href="orig_link">{{ orig_link }}</a></q-item-label>
                            </q-item-section>
                        </q-item>

                        <q-item clickable v-ripple>
                            <q-item-section>
                                <q-item-label><strong>Shortened URL:</strong>&nbsp;<a :href="shortened_link">{{ shortened_link }}</a></q-item-label>
                            </q-item-section>
                        </q-item>

                        <q-item clickable v-ripple>
                            <q-item-section>
                                <q-item-label><strong>Creation date:</strong> {{ format_date(creation_date) }}</q-item-label>
                            </q-item-section>
                        </q-item>

                        <q-item clickable v-ripple>
                            <q-item-section>
                                <q-item-label><strong>Total clicks:</strong> {{ total_clicks }}</q-item-label>
                                <q-item-label caption>Over {{ days_since_creation }} days</q-item-label>
                            </q-item-section>
                        </q-item>
                    </q-list>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 items-center">
                  <div>
                    <bar-chart
                    :options="options"
                    :chart-data="datasets"
                    :styles="chartStyle">
                    </bar-chart>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <q-btn
                    outlined
                    rounded
                    no-caps
                    v-for="(item, idx) in data_view_options"
                    :key="idx"
                    @click='current_data_view = idx'
                    :label=item
                    style="margin-left: 10px"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Problem is, this is what it looks like on a mobile screen:

[image: mobile]

I would like my layout to be somewhat responsive and handle this situation by placing the list on the left and the chart on the right onto separate rows if they don't both fit in the same row (e.g., with smaller screens).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you would need responsive grid [columns](https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/row#Responsive-classes). In your case it set to `col-4` and `col-6`, it'll apply those columns starting from the smallest screen to the biggest. Notice that there is 12 columns total and you're aligning your 10 columns to the center.

For your case you need classes `col-12 col-md-4`, `col-12 col-md-6` respectfully. Then it'll start from 12 columns for on the small screen and it'll jump to col-4/col-6 on the tablet screen.

(if it's not enough set it to `col-12 col-lg-4`, `col-12 col-lg-6`)